# Android: HowTo generate Jar for the added framework

Tags: android, frameworks, jar, makefile

I am trying to add some 3rd part framework in android code. The framework is set of java files.

My questions is how to generate Android Specific Jar for this framework so that my applications can use it. What and where am I missing the generation of Jar.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to generate jars is create an android project, put the classes inside a package on the src folder and then export the src folder as JAR with Eclipse.

Then add that Jar in your build path on the main project